# Play store reports “Your device isn't compatible with this version” but it installs via adb just fine on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

I have an app I released to a private Google Play Alpha. I can install this exact same APK to my Android Emulator just fine with
 adb pm install

but through the Google Play store it is marked for this exact same Emulator as

Your device isn't compatible with this version.

This is the same apk. I can't figure out how to get any information on why the play store thinks it's not compatible.

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0"
package="com.company.example"
platformBuildVersionCode="26"
platformBuildVersionName="8.0.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.0.0-alpha1" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.company.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="0x2" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.company.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f0b01b8"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f090022"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f030000"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@ref/0x7f02005b" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@ref/0x7f0e001d" />

        <service
            android:name="com.company.example.MyFirebaseMessagingService">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.company.example.FCMbroadcast"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category
                    android:name="com.servpro.activity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.company.example.SplashScreen">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter
                android:priority="-500">

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
            android:enabled="true">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category
                    android:name="com.company.example" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter
                android:priority="-500">

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.company.example.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@ref/0x7f0d0006" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My emulator version is Android 8.0.0 and API is 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem it's used Wifi feature permission emulator was not have wifi so i add following code like wifi is not needed compulsory it's solved my problem.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="false" />
```